# Move the same image according to the button I hover over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 8 buttons (images) on the page, all in the same line. And one hidden image(red rectangular box) with no text on it. I want to display the same red box just below the button(image) I hover over with dynamic text on the image(which would be according to the link of the button)

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="imageRings">
    <img id="ringOne" class="rotate" src="images/ring1.png">
    <img id="ringTwo" class="rotate" src="images/ring2.png">
    <img id="ringThree" class="rotate" src="images/ring3.png">
    <img id="ringFour" class="rotate" src="images/ring4.png">
    <img id="ringFive" class="rotate" src="images/ring5.png">
    <img id="ringSix" class="rotate" src="images/ring6.png">
    <img id="ringSeven" class="rotate" src="images/ring7.png">
    <img id="ringEight" class="rotate" src="images/ring8.png">
    </div>
```

So these are the images on which when I hover I want an image to appear just below the respective image I hover over, and text on it depending on the link(i mean i should be able to modify the text displayed on the rectangular box)

I know I haven't given much code to begin with but I dont know what else to provide. All I am missing from the above code is the code of rectangular box image, but I havent written it anywhere as the position is what needs to determined and changed according to the hovering.

Comment: @Palash I had written 8 different lines of images to display on the hovering, I mean next to every image I had written "<img id="box" class="rotate" src="images/rectangle.png">" and changed the visibility by $('#ringOne').hover(function() {
    $('#box').show()
}, function() {
    $('#box').hide()
});
And so on for rest of the images..

Comment: Can you alter the HTML? I would recommend putting them in an unordered list instead of free floating like that. Based on how the html is now, you would need to get the current position of the image you're hovered over and apply it to the rectangle with some offsetting; however if each image was in a <li> then you could simply append the rectangle to each one and not bother with the math. Just need to make your <li>'s inline.

Comment: @Syon I can alter the HTML, how would I do it with <li's> I am not that familiar with those tags. And how would I dynamically append them. Can you please jsfiddle it. Appreciate the help..

Comment: posted an answer below with jsFiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your images in divisions and/or lists as follows

```
<div id="hover">
<div class="ima 1">
<img src="your_img_1" />
<div class="fill">
</div></div>
<div class="ima 3">
<img src="your_img_2" />
<div class="fill">
</div></div>
<div class="ima 2">
<img src="your_img_3" />
<div class="fill">
</div>
</div></div>
```

Position as

```
.ima{
float:left /*Float to make parallel*/
}

img{
display:block;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.ima img').hover(function(){
$(this).parent().find('.fill').html('<img src="image" />');
},
function(){
$(this).parent().find('.fill').html('  ');
}
);
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, but the images are not hiding after moving the mouse away and i dont know why but they are not floating left as well.. I jsfiddled it.. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7tsd/2/  Appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: back to you in 5 mins..il test it on ur fiddle

Comment: And when I hover over the first image the second and third  automatically dropdown

Comment: i forgot to close a few tages..my fault

Answer (score 1):

Try this; place your images in an inline `<li>`, then you can append that .rect div to each one on hover. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/f7tsd/) for an example as well.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="imageRings">
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring1.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring2.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring3.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring4.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring5.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring6.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring7.png"></li>
    <li><img class="rotate" src="images/ring8.png"></li>
</ul>
<div class="rect"></div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('imageRings img').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).closest('li').append($('.rect'));
        $('.rect').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.rect').hide()
    }
})​;
```

**CSS**

```
#imageRings li{display:inline-block;}
.rect{border:1px solid red;background:#a55;height:20px;display:none;}​
```

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle also, it is also not working. But appreciate all the help, thanks sir.

Comment: @kapilchhattani wow - sorry, I forgot to save my update. heres the correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/f7tsd/3/